# How to find duration between last login time and current time?

Tags: php, time

I googled for solutions and edited some parts which suits how i wanted the function to be. This is how it looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT *from role,user WHERE user_name='$entered_username' AND PASSWORD = SHA1('$entered_password') AND user.role_id = role.role_id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $update = "UPDATE `user` SET last_login = NOW() WHERE user_name='$entered_username' ";
        $_SESSION['lastlog'] = $row['last_login'];


        $time = strtotime($_SESSION['lastlog']]);
        function humanTiming($time) {

            $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

            $tokens = array(
                31536000 => 'year',
                2592000 => 'month',
                604800 => 'week',
                86400 => 'day',
                3600 => 'hour',
                60 => 'minute',
                1 => 'second'
            );

            foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
                if ($time < $unit)
                    continue;
                $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                return $numberOfUnits . ' ' . $text . (($numberOfUnits > 1) ? 's' : '');
            }
        }
```

In html,

```
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            if ($_SESSION['role_id'] == "Admin") {
                ?>
<?php echo 'You logged in ' . humanTiming($time) . ' ago'; ?>
```

After trying this out, it managed to display out the time it calculates in hours. Eg."You logged in 23 hours ago". After I logged the user out, and then log in again, it only displays "You logged in ago". It did not display the time even in seconds after I logged out. How do I fix this?

Comment: Often very small intervals are displayed as "just now" rather than "2 seconds ago".

Answer (score 0):

I am just editing your function. I think its syntax error. Hope this helps:

```
 $time = "";
    $query = "SELECT *from role,user WHERE user_name='$entered_username' AND PASSWORD = SHA1('$entered_password') AND user.role_id = role.role_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $update = "UPDATE `user` SET last_login = NOW() WHERE user_name='$entered_username' ";
            $_SESSION['lastlog'] = $row['last_login'];


            $time = strtotime($_SESSION['lastlog']]);
    }
            function humanTiming($time) {

                $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

                $tokens = array(
                    31536000 => 'year',
                    2592000 => 'month',
                    604800 => 'week',
                    86400 => 'day',
                    3600 => 'hour',
                    60 => 'minute',
                    1 => 'second'
                );
             $humanTime = "";
                foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
                    if ($time < $unit)
                        continue;
                    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                    $humanTime .= $numberOfUnits . ' ' . $text . (($numberOfUnits > 1) ? 's' : '');
                }
                return $humanTime; //you should return string like this
            }
```

**Edit** : Your function was not returning any string, so it wasn't displayed.

**Question** : Why are you using function in if statement??? I guess you know the answer.